# cost not updating in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the following code from Sirajalogy. https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_use_Tensorflow_for_classification-LIVE/blob/master/demo.ipynbIt 
It has been modified to accept my own .csv with different dimensions than the one used in his example.

```
import pandas as pd             
import numpy as np               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import tensorflow as tf          # Fire from the gods
dataframe = pd.read_csv("jfkspxs.csv") 
dataframe = dataframe.drop(["Field6", "Field9", "rowid"], axis=1)

inputX = dataframe.loc[:, ['Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4', 'Field5', 'Field7', 'Field8', 'Field10']].as_matrix()
inputY = dataframe.loc[:, ["y1"]].as_matrix()

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 2000
display_step = 50
n_samples = inputY.size

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 7])              
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([7, 1]))          
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))             

y_values = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)   
y = tf.nn.softmax(y_values)                
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])   

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_ - y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(training_epochs):  
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_: inputY}))
if (i) % display_step == 0:
        cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_:inputY})
        print ("Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc))
```

The code is running, but producing the following cost updates.

```
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0050 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0100 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0150 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0200 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0250 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0300 cost= 0.271760166
Training step: 0350 cost= 0.271760166
etc.
```

Question: Why are the costs not updating with each training step?
Thanks!

Comment: To help you reproduce the error, it would be nice to know how to get a copy of the "jfkspxs.csv" file that you are using. Is it available for download anywhere?

Comment: https://github.com/jhsmith12345/tensorflow

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: your gradients are zero, therefore your weights doesn't change. You provide single dimension (batch_size, 1) to softmax. This makes output of softmax a constant (1). This makes it's gradient be zero.

Solutions:

If you're doing a logistic regression, please use `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_values, y_)`

If you're doing a linear regression, please use (i.e. don't use softmax):
`cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_ - y_values, 2))/(2*n_samples)`

If you insist on mixing softmax and MSE, please use following instead of softmax:
`y = tf.reciprocal(1 + tf.exp(-y_values))`

Comment: Used your third solution and cost is now updating. Thank you!